# SoapUi AMF Request do login

Tags: groovy, soapui, amf

I downloaded Soapui and configured it to do AMF Request.
My server is using spring security so i have to be logged in to call functions.

Here is a screenshot : http://hpics.li/a632c3e

How can i set in the groovy script in the windows, be logged in before ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SoapUI document described you can enable AMF session.
Open your TestCase and click on the Options button. In the AMF tab you can set whether you need to use session and authorize  to an AMF service for all AMF requests in your TestCase.

see: http://www.soapui.org/AMF/calling-amf-services.html